# how to login on paypal using mechanize in python?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, paypal, mechanize-python

I have to login on paypal using mechanize in python.I tried many codes but invent.Same code is applicable for login on gmail but not work for paypal login.I tried code below..

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser
import time,urllib2
from os import system
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

user='userID'
pas='password'
# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br. set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;    rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://www.paypal.com/signin?country.x=IN&locale.x=en_IN')
##br.open('https://www.paypal.com/')
br.select_form(name='login')
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form["login_email"]=user
br.form["login_password"]=pas
br.submit()
```

I got an error `httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Anyone can help me? please answer me.